# How to set auth_basic using condition?

Tags: nginx

I need to configure my `Nginx` site configuration to show a password only in my development server. Infact, I'm using `CI/CD` which deploy the app using `Docker` on production, but I don't need to show the password on production.

The development server usually end with a specific domain like: `appname.example.com`.

Is there a way to show the authentication only in development?

This is my configuration:

```
server {
    root   /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/html/public/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_pass   php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block to get an `auth_basic` directive argument from the [`$host`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) variable value:

```
map $host $realm {
    appname.example.com  "Resticted content";
    default              off;
}

server {
    root   /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    auth_basic $realm;
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/html/public/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can use regex expressions with the `map` directive using `~` modifier, for example

```
map $host $realm {
    ~appname\.example\.com$  "Resticted content";
    default                  off;
}
```