# Nginx uses if to match URL parameters

Tags: nginx

```
auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
auth_basic_user_file /www/server/nginx/.passwd;
location / {
    error_page 418 = @418;
    if ($args ~* "user/view/plugins"){
        return 418;
    }
}
location @418{
  auth_basic off;
}
```

I want to use nginx's if to determine if there are some values in the matching URL parameters, but my PHP code uses a pseudo-static technique. In normal requests, the parameters are directly in the/root background. The same request, different request methods, if cannot match the parameters
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFeI0.png)

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, you are trying to do it is a really weird way. You can try the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69538528/7121513) (use `map $args $realm { ... }` instead).

Comment: It is considered bad practice to post/link to images when you can post the text into your question instead. Please consider removing the image and replacing this with the relevant text. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example